# Move button from outside the activity to a particular position

Tags: android

I have multiple buttons aligned vertically(one below the other) in an activity and I want those buttons to appear on the screen as if user sees it coming from outside of the screen(on X axis) when the activity loads. I have gone through many examples but could not find a real solution. If you can provide the link or an example, that would be great. Earlier, I used translation but the button moves from its real position to outside and comes back to its original position. My requirement is to have only to have those buttons come from outside of the screen to its original position.

Snippet in main activity:

```
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

buttonAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, 
R.anim.button_animation);

button1.setAnimation(buttonAnimation);
button2.setAnimation(buttonAnimation);
button3.setAnimation(buttonAnimation);
button4.setAnimation(buttonAnimation);
```

res/anim/button_animation.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%p"
        android:duration="500"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

In this code, the button is going outside of the screen and coming to its original position. I need to have this only coming from outside to its real position. Basically, I am not sure what will be the best approach to do this.

Comment: I mean… what he heck… please, do everybody a favor a have the decency to show the code you wrote, the code that fails, where you think it fails, what you’ve done to try to make it work and what happened afterwards, and what motivated you to ask “the internet” to write this code for you… For free, let me tell you that if you’re using AnimatorSets, and such, you may need to ensure the transformations (translation in your case) *stays* after the animation is over. Anyway… post your code or you will not get a lot of help :/

Answer (score 0):

Use this animation. Only adjust value in your project.Pay attention first position of buttons must be the final position after animation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked as expected. My next requirement is to move those buttons completely out of the screen on another button click. I tried with little change in the animation file. 
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
but this makes the button go out of the screen and then in a flash, it comes back to its original position. Can I make it completely go outside of the screen. Please let me know.

Comment: You must add this line to your code yourAnimationName.setFillAfter(true);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to freely move the Buttons by changing their left and top margins your layout should be a RelativeLayout and the buttons should not have rules like "align_below" that relate to each other or to the Parent.